# Running gunicorn on Ubuntu in a conda environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, gunicorn, conda

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu.  I have my WSGI file set up, but I'm having some issues running gunicorn.  At first, I installed gunicorn with `sudo apt-get install gunicorn`.  However, it ran with the wrong version of python, and it threw import errors for each of the modules my Flask app uses.  I ascertained that this was due to the fact that I use conda as an environment manager, and because installing with `apt-get` placed gunicorn outside of the purview virtual environment.  So, I uninstalled gunicorn (`sudo apt-get purge gunicorn`) and reinstalled it through conda (`conda install gunicorn`).  Now, when I run gunicorn (`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app`), I don't get a 50 line traceback.  I do, however, get the following error: `-bash: /usr/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory`.  I tried uninstalling gunicorn and reinstalling with pip, but I still get the same error.  I've tried searching Google and StackOverflow for solutions, but all I've discovered is that I should be installing gunicorn within a virtual environment to overcome this error (which, I beleive, I'm already doing).  I'm guessing there's an easy fix to this, and that the problem is related to my ineptitude, as opposed to conda or something else.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I was right - the problem is entirely related to my own ineptitude.  Rather than deleting this question, though, I'm going to answer it myself and leave it here in case any future fledgling developers run into the same problem.  The issue, as it turns out, is that I was running `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app` in the wrong directory.  After I `cd` into the directory containing `wsgi.py`, gunicorn works just fine.  The takeaway: gunicorn must be run from within the directory containing `wsgi.py`.